# Abnormal list behaviour

Tags: python

I was working on some problem and came across this.

Python code

```
row=[]
col=[]
init=[-1,-1]
```

Now I append this `init` to `row` and `col`.

```
row.append(init)
row.append(init)

col.append(init)
col.append(init)
```

Therefore `row = [[-1,-1],[-1,-1]]` and `col = [[-1,-1],[-1,-1]]`

Now when i change `init[0] = 9` my `row` and `col` becomes
`row = [[9,-1],[9,-1]]` and `col = [[9,-1],[9,-1]]`

Comment: You might want to say why you think this is abnormal, because this probably looks normal to most python programmers.

Comment: @wrgrs I'm a Python programmer, and while the behavior the program exhibits is perfectly normal (expected, even) to me, I have no trouble imagining why OP considers this abnormal (expecting a copy to be made, or more generally expecting call by value instead of call by sharing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you store the same reference to the object `init` over and over. So when you modify the object everyone sees it.

You could try `append`ing copies of the list instead. One way for example could be:

```
row.append(list(init))
```

There's more than one way to [clone a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/714501).

Comment: +1, though I think list(init) is less cryptic for newcomers :)

Comment: Agreed, as an explanation, `[:]` takes a slice from the start to the end of the list, effectively copying it. `list()` will do the same job more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help explaining why

http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

Comment: It is, and it's great at it, but if you have nothing else to say, [it's not considered a good answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231) -- I think a comment is a better place to do this. I know, you're new and aren't even allowed to post comments yet, just for the future.